# How to speed up pygame on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to make a set of gauges on a screen for my car.
This program runs without issues on Windows, but on the Raspberry Pi, it struggles.

The issue I'm having is with the speed of pygame. Is there any simple way to speed this up? I've tried only drawing a single gauge needle, but it still is updating too slow.

```
import pygame
from controlprog import goals, farloop
import random
import time
#import threading
# Set up the drawing window
flags = pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([0,0], flags)
tempsurf = pygame.Surface((3000, 2000))
pygame.event.set_allowed([])
running = True
zeroDeg = 225
maxDeg = -45
gauge = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/gaugelow.png').convert_alpha()
needleOrd = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/needle.png').convert_alpha()
background = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/back2.png').convert()
mainback = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/mainback.png').convert()
textlayer = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge/images/textblu.png').convert_alpha()
splash = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/splash.png').convert_alpha()
window = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/window.png').convert()
task = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/task.png').convert()
f1 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/1.jpg').convert()
f2 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/2.jpg').convert()
f3 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/3.jpg').convert()
f4 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/4.jpg').convert()
f5 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/5.jpg').convert()
f6 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/6.jpg').convert()
f7 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/7.jpg').convert()
f8 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/8.jpg').convert()
f9 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/9.jpg').convert()
f10 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/10.jpg').convert()
f11 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/11.jpg').convert()
f12 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/12.jpg').convert()
f13 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/13.jpg').convert()
f14 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/14.jpg').convert()
f15 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/15.jpg').convert()
f16 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/16.jpg').convert()
f17 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/17.jpg').convert()
f18 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/18.jpg').convert()
K4 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/4k.jpg').convert()
K7 = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/7k.jpg').convert()
KS = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/pigauge2/images/frame/ks.jpg').convert()
needle = needleOrd
ang = zeroDeg
extGoal = 0
moveNumOrg = 10
firstRun = True

def showshit():
    global tempsurf
    #tempsurf = pygame.transform.smoothscale(tempsurf, (1000,800))
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(tempsurf, (2800, 1850)), (32,15))
    #pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(75,75,125,125))
    pygame.display.update()

def rotate(im, angle, pivot):
    # rotate the leg image around the pivot
    image = pygame.transform.rotate(im.copy(), angle)
    rect = image.get_rect()
    rect.center = pivot
    return image, rect


def drawNeedle(goal, pos):
    global firstRun, ang, done, moveNum
    if firstRun:
        ang = zeroDeg
    firstRun = False
    needle2, pos2 = rotate(needleOrd.copy(), ang, pos)
    tempsurf.blit(needle2, pos2)
    goaltrue = -goal + 225
    if ang != goaltrue:
        if ang < goaltrue:
            ang = ang + moveNum
        if ang > goaltrue:
            ang = ang - moveNum
        done = False
    if (ang + moveNum) > goaltrue and (ang - moveNum) < goaltrue:
        ang = goaltrue

moveNum = 1

for i in range(0, 5):
    tempsurf.blit(f2, (0,-30))
    showshit()
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    tempsurf.blit(f1, (0,-30))
    showshit()
    pygame.time.delay(500)

tempsurf.blit(f2, (0,-30))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(200)


tempsurf.blit(splash, (0,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(3000)

for i in range(0,2):
    tempsurf.fill((0,0,0))
    tempsurf.blit(f5, (0, -30))
    showshit()
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    tempsurf.blit(f4, (0, -30))
    showshit()
    pygame.time.delay(500)

tempsurf.blit(f5, (0, -30))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(400)
f2 = None
f5 = None
f4 = None
f1 = None
f3 = None
tempsurf.blit(f6, (0, 0))
showshit()
f6 = None
pygame.time.delay(2000)
tempsurf.blit(f7, (0,0))
showshit()
f7 = None
pygame.time.delay(2000)
tempsurf.blit(f8, (0,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(3000)
tempsurf.blit(f9, (0,0))
showshit()
f9 = None
pygame.time.delay(100)
tempsurf.blit(f10, (0,0))
showshit()
f10 = None
pygame.time.delay(2500)
tempsurf.blit(f11, (0,0))
showshit()
f11 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f12, (0,0))
showshit()
f12 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f13, (0,0))
showshit()
f13 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(K4, (0,0))
showshit()
K4 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f14, (0,0))
showshit()
f14 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f15, (0,0))
showshit()
f15 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(K7, (0,0))
showshit()
K7 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f16, (0,0))
showshit()
f16 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f17, (0,0))
showshit()
f17 = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(KS, (0,0))
showshit()
KS = None
pygame.time.delay((random.randint(100,700)))
tempsurf.blit(f18, (0,0))
showshit()
f18 = None
pygame.time.delay(800)
tempsurf.blit(f8, (0,0))
showshit()
f8 = None
pygame.time.delay(2700)
tempsurf.blit(background, (0,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(1500)

#tempsurf.blit(textlayer, (0,0))
tempsurf.blit(window, (6,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(500)
tempsurf.blit(window, (245,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(300)
tempsurf.blit(window,(484,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(400)
tempsurf.blit(window, (6,240))
tempsurf.blit(task, (0, 460))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(600)
tempsurf.blit(window, (245, 240))
tempsurf.blit(task, (0, 460))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(300)
tempsurf.blit(window, (484, 240))
tempsurf.blit(task, (0, 460))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(400)
tempsurf.blit(textlayer, (0,0))
showshit()
pygame.time.delay(2000)



#       top row of gauges
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (30, 30))
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (270, 30))
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (510, 30))

#       bottom row of gauges
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (30, 270))
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (270, 270))
tempsurf.blit(gauge, (510, 270))
window = None
gauge = None
task = None

showshit()

#def threadfunc():
    #global extGoal
    #while True:
        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (117.5, 117.5))
        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (357.5, 117.5))
        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (597.5, 117.5))

        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (117.5, 357.5))
        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (357.5, 357.5))
        #drawNeedle(extGoal, (597.5, 357.5))


moveNum = moveNumOrg
tempsurf.blit(background, (0,0))
tempsurf.blit(textlayer, (0,0))
background = None
textlayer = None
ang = zeroDeg
#x = threading.Thread(target=threadfunc)
#x.start()
while 1:

    # Did the user click the window close butt           running = False

    #starttime= time.time()
    #farloop()
    #print("farloop --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - starttime))
    #starttime = time.time()
    #extGoal = goals()
    #print("get goal --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - starttime))

    if ang == zeroDeg:
        extGoal=270
    if ang == maxDeg:
        extGoal=0

    tempsurf.blit(mainback, (0,0))

    drawNeedle(extGoal, (117.5, 117.5))
    drawNeedle(extGoal, (357.5, 117.5))
    drawNeedle(extGoal, (597.5, 117.5))

    drawNeedle(extGoal, (117.5, 357.5))
    drawNeedle(extGoal, (357.5, 357.5))
    drawNeedle(extGoal, (597.5, 357.5))
    showshit()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do the same thing everybody should do when they want to speed up code: profile it. This will tell you where most time is spent and on what parts of the code you should focus your attention. It's as simple as using `time.time()` and `print()`.

Comment: maybe you should reduce some operations. Do you really have to `scale()` in every `blit()` - maybe you should scale all elements only once and later use these elements. I don't know if you have to `.copy()` when you `rotate()` - `rotate` gives new image and it doesn't change old one.

Comment: do you really need so many images? Maybe you can blit some images on one surface and later blit only this single surface. BTW: Maybe you should keep elements on list instead of using `f1, f2, etc.` and then you could use `for`-loop - it could make code shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I never thought about any of that, it should help a lot! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) does not manipulate the original image. Therefore, there is no need to copy the original image:

<s>`image = pygame.transform.rotate(im.copy(), angle)`</s>

```py
def rotate(im, angle, pivot):
    # rotate the leg image around the pivot
    image = pygame.transform.rotate(im, angle)
    rect = image.get_rect(center = pivot)
    return image, rect
```

<s>`needle2, pos2 = rotate(needleOrd.copy(), ang, pos)`</s>

```py
def drawNeedle(goal, pos):
    global firstRun, ang, done, moveNum
    if firstRun:
        ang = zeroDeg
    firstRun = False
    needle2, pos2 = rotate(needleOrd, ang, pos)

    # [...]
```